# Which JavaScript lightbox is most like the one at the apple website? (link provided)

Tags: javascript, popup, lightbox

If you click on:

http://store.apple.com/us/product/MAC_OS_X_SNGL

And then click on **"Find out which version you're using"**:

[Apple website http://imgbag.com/josh/joshx/StackOverflow/AppleWebsite.jpg](http://imgbag.com/josh/joshx/StackOverflow/AppleWebsite.jpg)

I appreciate that they probably paid it to be royally customised, but I can't seem to find one that is close in terms of how it pops up and style etc.

Comment: that runs remarkably slow on chrome and IE7 on my box, is it just me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This one - FancyZoom](http://orderedlist.com/articles/fancyzoom-meet-jquery) - is almost exactly the same.